# Conditionals: "if after all," "if after life," and "as if I'm/I was/I were"

Tags: conditional-constructions

Does the use of "if after" change nothing with the rules of if-conditionals?

Are these sentences okay?

> If after all we'**ll** do **will** make no effect, then why are we still trying?
>
> If after all we('re) do(ing) will make no effect, then why are we still trying?
>
> If after all we're about to do makes no effect, then why are we still trying?

I know you can't **will** or **would** in the if-clause, but I'm confused because there can be two **will** in this example.

Should I choose one and leave the other? Or get rid of both of them?

> If after all we do makes no effect, then why are we still trying?

What about "if after life"? Should I use **the** type 1 conditional (possible) or **the** type 2 conditional (hypothetical). And is it okay to combine if-conditionals?

> If after life I go to your room, will you be scared as if you see a zombie?

Lastly, is it never okay to say **as** **if** **I'm** or **as** **if** **I** **was**, so always use **as** **if** **I** **were**? Or it depends on how likely something is, but still never **as** **if** **I** **was**?

Mini question, shouldn't I use **the** there? Why or why not?

Comment: I have a problem parsing all of your _after all_ sentences. I'm missing an object. You _could_ say _if, after all, **what** we do makes no difference..._. Note that you don't _make_ an effect. You _have an effect_,  or you _make a difference_. I think you are misunderstanding the meaning of _after all_. It just means "in the end". Try substituting that for _after all_ and you will see where your sentence goes wrong: _If in the end we do makes no difference_ doesn't sound right, does it?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I think I just needed to know their meanings and always use parenthetical commas, right? And for the after life, it just means "life after death," about people's beliefs. So if I put two commas at both end, it'll make sense now. But I still don't know about which word to choose after as if. I've asked another question, please answer in that if you know.

Comment: _After all_ is an idiom. _After_ doesn't relate to _if_ at all here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is more than one question here.

Answer (score 0):

> If after all we'll do will make no effect, then why are we still trying?
>   If after all we('re) do(ing) will make no effect, then why are we still trying?
>   If after all we're about to do makes no effect, then why are we still trying?

Non of these three sentences are correct, it should be your fourth sentence

> If after all **we do** will **have** no effect, then why are we still trying?

and is usually stated as

> If **everything** we do will have no effect, then why are we still trying?

the "*after*" is implied.

Your final sentence is not very clear

> If after life I go to your room, will you be scared as if you see a zombie?

are you talking about your death or the other person's death?
Since you probably mean

> If after **I die** I go to your room, will you be scared **that** you **will** see a zombie?

Comment: None of these sentences is correct. :)

Comment: Peter's or mine? I doubt all of them. But I learned that I should use parenthetical commas when I use "after all" and "after life."

Comment: My own preference would be *If what we do has no effect, then why are we still trying?* or better still *If what we are doing will make no difference, then why are we still trying?*